# Row operation in kdb update statement with multiple parameters

Tags: kdb

```
myFunc:{[x]
   // ...
}
```

I know i can perform a row operation on my table using the update statement this way:

```
update newVal: myFunc each someField from someTable;
```

Now if my function takes 2 params:

```
myFunc2: {[x;y]
   // x and y are different types
}
```

How do i now pass in two params per row operation? I tried these:

```
update newVal: myFunc2 each someField, otherField from someTable;
update newVal: myFunc2 . (someField;otherField) from someTable;
```

Didn't seem to work, what is the right way to pass more than 1 params to a function in an update stmt?

Comment: Similar question can be found here with a good answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338213/q-apply-function-on-table-rowwise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [q - apply function on table rowwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338213/q-apply-function-on-table-rowwise)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [each-both](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both) adverb `'` as in example below

```
update newVal: myFunc2'[someField;otherField] from someTable
```

Comment: Would this work say if i have a function which takes more than 2 params? If i understand the correctly this means someField myFunc2' otherField....

Comment: Yes, `'` will work for any number of parameters.
Thought `a func' b` construct works only for two, `func'[a;b;c;...]` should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

```
update {x+y}'[a;b] from ([] a:1 2 3; b:10 20 30)
```

a  b c 1 10 11 2 20 22 3 30 33

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO since its code only answer.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users –